# Scraping text with Python/Selenium and converting CSS formatting to Markdown

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, format

I am using Selenium in Python to scrape text from a website. I get the element containing each piece of text by its ID, store it in a variable called `block`, and can then access the text via `block.text`.

The thing is, I need to retain the formatting (e.g., bold, italic, etc.). My plan was to find these parts of the text by class name (e.g., `class="bold"`) and modify the text of the element with the appropriate Markdown syntax (e.g., `some bold text` would become `**some bold text**`). I could then store this in a database and convert the Markdown back to HTML or CSS later.

The problem is that I can't simply change the text of each formatted element. If I try to do something like `element.text = 'x'`, I get `AttributeError: can't set attribute`. This is a problem because I would have wanted to loop through the formatted elements, add the Markdown, and then have this be reflected in the overarching `block.text` that contains all of these formatted elements. I could then store that text in a database.

So, while I can easily get a list of all the words and phrases within the larger texts that are, e.g., bold, I see no practical way of performing operations on them that will modify the larger texts to which they belong. There must be a reasonable way of doing this, but my research has turned up nothing very helpful.